# Looking for web platform/service that enables me to track and reporting on custom metrics over time

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, analytics, web-analytics-tools

We have 6 or 7 key metrics that we want to track on a daily, weekly and monthly basis.  We have an iOS app with a backend service. Right now we do this by just querying out DB and calculating the metric values on the fly for a daily report email.

We want to have the metrics tracked on a daily basis outside of email so we can plot it over time. e.g:

**7/26/2011**

- Foo Metric = 10,294
- Bar Metric = 495

**7/27/2011**

- Foo Metric = 10,596
- Bar Metric = 388

etc

So essentially storing key+value pairs based on date with the keys being from a normalized set.

I could write these metrics to a DB and use google charts to do my plots of the change, but I figure this is a common scenario and there must be an service that solves this.

I don't want to stand up any of my own hardware for this and would love to find a turnkey solution that exists.  I've looked at Google Analytics, but it doesn't support arbitrary key values injected in to track. I've also checked out other web analytics services (chartbeat, clicky, woopra, etc) but none of them support arbitrary name value pairs either.

I've looked at "Dashboard" services like Geckoboard and Dashboard.me, but they are focused too much on a current point in time and won't let me graph out arbitrary date ranges (e.g. I want to see "# of Foo" June 1-June 30.

Any recommendations for turn key solutions that exist that we can leverage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered something like [StatHat](http://www.stathat.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I am having great success with Flurry Analytics in my iOS applications.  http://www.flurry.com/

Comment: Flurry is great for analytics, however, it doesn't do what I'm asking in this question.  It won't store arbitrary name value pairs I submit.